# Freshmen, Sophomores, Juniors, Seniors - what category?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a single-word category for the status Freshmen, Sophomores, Juniors, Seniors? I've heard it called as "batch status" but can't seem to find the right single-word category for it.

Comment: @pageman: Don't take this the wrong way, but I really do think it's only fair to flag up in the original question if you're looking for a 'set name' word to be used in a 'programming' design context. If you were actually looking to name a C++ class, as opposed to just a database fieldname, @Robusto wouldn't have needed to waste time proposing the actual word *class* (although the mind boggles at whether one could actually successfully implement a class called "class").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: '... the mind boggles at whether one could actually successfully implement a class called "class"'. Completely legal to do so in Java as long as the name of the class is "Class" (upper-case 'C'). Not sure about C++ however.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I was careful not to capitalise it when I wrote the (potential?) classname "class". And again lol. You could probably recompile an open-source C++ compiler after replacing all occurences of the literal "class" with, say "clAss". Then code the freaky implementation program with that. My mind continues to boggle, but that way madness lies...

Comment: @Fumble flag away - who's going to stop you but your conscience? :)

Comment: Hopefully no-one. But I didn't intend any association with EL&U's support for 'flagging'. I just thought since we often find ourselves asking OP for more 'context' on a question, you might consider your intended use of any answer you get here to be a useful bit of context that could have been supplied. No biggie.

Comment: @Fumble I derived my question from somebody else's need for a database name - for myself, I'm just curious what that word would have been.

Comment: @pageman: Fair enough. In the circumstances my point becomes somewhat less meaningful. But you will appreciate we have had questions here which are effectively asking "What should I call this programming class?", without explicitly acknowledging that highly restricted context. My apologies for misclassifying yours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might consider *class* as a generic noun that covers these terms.

> All members of the junior class will become seniors next year.
>
> David is an upperclassman now that he's in his third year at Brandeis.

But despite what others have stated, I believe the term "cohort" has a slightly different connotation. It means

> **Cohort** (educational group) A cohort is a group of students who work through a curriculum together to achieve the same academic degree together. A cohort forms when the students begin the curriculum and typically does not admit new members afterward. [Wikipedia]

Here's [another reference](http://www.brighthub.com/education/online-learning/articles/25514.aspx#ixzz1OPmsIhQ0) for cohort:

> Cohort study is when a group of students, 12-25 (this is a general number that may vary by college), start and finish their degree together. They are accepted into the same program, take their classes together, and graduate together, building relationships with one another as they do.

This would seem to invalidate the notion that *cohort* could be used. Typically juniors, seniors and the rest do admit new members (transfers, etc.) and they don't all pursue the same academic degree.

Comment: point taken - need the single-word for a database - "class" might not work but you've made a compelling argument for it :)

Answer (score 5):

*"Year"*?

*"Cohort"*?

or you could say that students are grouped by their *"Expected graduation date"*.

Comment: Cohort seems to be the right word! I'll wait for more answers but that feels right! :)

Comment: @pageman: As per @Robusto's answer, I'm not sure *cohort* is exactly right (though it's clearly closely related). My vote is for the first option in this answer, namely *year* :)

Answer (score 2):

We don't really use any of these terms in the UK, so maybe I'm not qualified to answer. But I think in general the only significant subcategories within tertiary education are *first-year* and *final year* students.

Most courses tend to be 2-4 years, within which it often makes a difference if someone's just starting or about to finish, but there's little reason for most of us to distinguish any particular year-group somewhere between those limits.

One group who *are* likely to need to refer to specific year-groups are the staff at the educational establishment. In the UK they probably normally do this by referring to the **2009 intake**, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a prof at a US university. We (I and people I hear from on this topic) call these classifications (freshman, etc.) "rank."

We don't use "cohort," because that denotes [a group that takes limited-availability classes together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_(educational_group)).

We don't use "class," because that denotes the year of graduation, not the current progress toward that year:  "class of 2020."

We don't use "grade"; that works in the US up through 12th grade, in high school, but colleges don't use it.

We may say "year":  "What year are you in?" maybe answered "I'm a junior." I think this is informal, and "rank" is the usual term I hear, but "year" can work too.

Answer (score 1):

Cohort. These words describe cohorts of students.

A better question is why American institutions aren't content to simply use ordinals (or cardinals) to describe their cohorts.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that, say, all dialects of English have names for days of the week instead of simply numbering them (like many other languages do): because why not?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Yes, but all European languages have names for days of the week, but I'm not aware of any other dialect of any language where there are words for all university cohorts.

Comment: @Marcin: The use of freshman, etc came directly over from England in the mid 1700's.  http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1982/whats-the-origin-of-sophomore

*sigh, someday I'll remember to hit shift + enter when typing a comment here, but apparently not today*  They're one of those 'English peculiarities' that we've kept. For high school students, however, they're still commonly referred to as '9th graders, 10th graders, etc' and not just 'freshmen, etc'.

Comment: @Darwy: Reading the article closely you will see that these are not "English" words, but words only used at Cambridge, and apparently Trinity, Dublin.

Comment: @Marcin if you read my comment closely I said they came OVER from England, not that they were 'English' in origin (they are quite obviously Greek). These designations were also used at Oxford for a short time.  They were 'imported' to the US during said time and have evolved somewhat since then, but their ancestry is indisputably from use by English academia.

Comment: @Darwy: "They're one of those 'English peculiarities' that we've kept." On any natural reading, you're describing them as "English" rather than merely in use in a particular English institution.

Comment: They are English peculiarities. They are Greek in origin (as many English words are), however their usage in that manner (the description of academic levels) is most definitely English. 

The same could be said about the Imperial Units still in use in the US: it was brought over from England and it's still in use.  To use a Southern vernacular, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: @Darwy: (a) "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" is much more widespread than the Southern US (b) That has absolutely application here (c) On your reasoning, if people at one school in England were to start enjoying salmiakki, then salmiakki would be an "English" food. That would obviously be misleading - just because the people are inside England, it is not English, it is of them and their specific institution.

Comment: @Marcin With regards to (a) the use is widespread, the origin is American: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it.html

(c) Your analogy is flawed. The use of sophister was not limited to a single university, both Cambridge AND Oxford utilized it for a period of time. 
A swift examination of online dictionaries lists sophister as follows:
*(Eng. Univ.)* A student who is advanced beyond the first year of his residence. [1913 Webster] 
The universities anglicised the word 'sophisms' when they called their students sophisters (users of sophisms)

Comment: @Darwy: Given that Webster is not a model of scholarship (after all, he decided to simplify spellings on his motion), and is an American source, that's a poor authority for the proposition that the term is "English" rather than institution specific.

Comment: @Marcin Of course, I was waiting for the inevitable "but that's Webster, what did he know?" reply.

The Collins Dictionary lists it as, "1. (esp formerly) a second-year undergraduate at certain British universities", Dictionary.com with, "Chiefly British . (especially formerly) a second or third year student at a university." and a side note that the word origin is 1350-1400 Middle English.

Comment: @Darwy: So why use Webster in the first place? Also, "certain British universities" is pretty weak for the claim in question, without any reference to the number or periods of usage.

Comment: @Darwy: My high school and college both insisted on using ordinals, but all of the students continue to use the names, including the neologism *supersenior* for fifth-year undergrads. Conversely, my college now insists that everyone refer to buildings by name (read: benefactor name), but everyone continues to use the numbers.

Comment: @Jon Copenhagen University has done the same for two of its campuses; they have 'new' maps and 'old' maps - so it's always a crapshoot whether or not you have the right building - some were given new names, some they just changed the number.  

@Marcin Webster is a perfectly acceptable dictionary for reasonable individuals. Encyclopedia.co.uk cites it for the definition of sophister, and further down on their page, the listing for sophomore says, "The word was probably introduced into the United States at an early date, from the University of Cambridge, England."

Comment: @Marcin: I'm really not sure why you're arguing here. Though the others are now uncommon, *freshman* is in use to this day (albeit almost always in the abbreviated form *fresher*) in the majority of UK universities to describe members of the new intake. Your answer would be greatly improved if you were to remove the uncalled-for dig in your second paragraph. It does not address the question and, as this thread shows, only serves to generate controversy.

Comment: @psmears: I have never heard freshman used at any of the UK universities I have attended, nor have I known anyone at universities I was not attending to use the word "freshman", with the exception of foreigners. The current term is "freshers", which is purely informal.

Comment: @Marcin: That seems to be entirely consistent with what I said :) I *have* come across *freshman*, though only on a handful of occasions, compared to thousands of uses of *fresher*. The latter may be informal but it is nonetheless related and entirely current in UK universities. And your answer would still be improved by a judicious edit :)

Comment: @psmears: I think it's a fair question why American universities have clung to a usage that has died out everywhere else, and seems to have no objective benefit in terms of clarity or anything else.

Comment: @Marcin Why do some people in England still use the 'stone' as a measure of their weight?  Preference? Tradition?

Comment: @Darwy: That's also a fair question. I suspect that the practice will drop off sharply when people born before 1970 cease to occupy a significant number of jobs in the communications media.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Grade

2.) Year

3.) Class (ex. Class of '19)

4.) Cohort